# Cannot import .ova

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, troubleshooting, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to import an .ova file into my VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits), but when I do this I get the following error:

```
Failed to import appliance
/media/USB/Respaldo 11 (Armando)/SW/Maquinas Virtuales/NAT64 (SLE 11, 3.0.101-0.31).ova
```

I tried uncompressed the .ova, I created a new virtual machine, then I added the .vmdk to the virtual machine created but didn't work.

Then, I tried to clonning and still didn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post any relevant bits from the VirtualBox log?  (Look in `~/.VirtualBox`)

Comment: @heavyd What's the path of the log?

Comment: I don't have a Linux machine with VirtualBox on it right now, so I can't tell you for sure.  On Windows the path is `~/.VirtualBox/VBoxSVC.log`

Comment: @heavyd Only I found this: [link](http://pastebin.com/L66bmAus) (VBox.log), [link](http://pastebin.com/55VL3JHN) (VBox.log.1)

Comment: You don't have a `VBoxSVC.log`?  I did verify that path is valid on Linux as well.  The logs your linked to are specific to a particular VM, and since it hasn't been imported yet, no VM specific log could be created yet.

Comment: No, apparently. I can't fount the path of the file